# How to map an array of objects to rows in a table using react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner to React and I want to map the hard coded array objects into table rows..
How to accomplish this with the minimum amount of coding?
The following is my code and I've used a class component to accomplish the task..

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../components/channelList/channelList.scss";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
// import { channelActions, channelSelectors } from './ducks';
import { optionsListActions } from "../../components/purchaseOptionListing/ducks";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ConfirmationModal from "./../../components/confirmationModal/ConfirmModal";
import ToastModal from "./../../components/Toast/ToastModal";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductListTable from "./../../components/ProductListTable/ProductListTable";
import ProductTableHeader from "./../../components/ProductTableHeader/ProductTableHeader";
import Spinner from "./../../components/spinner/spinner";
import ProvisioningMatrixListHeaderView from "./../userManagementListHeader/ProvisioningMatrixListHeader";

let data = [
  {
    col1: "col1",
    col2: "col2",
    col3: "col3",
    col4: "col4",
    col5: "col5",
    col6: "col6",
    col7: "col7",
    col8: "col8",
    col9: "col9",
    col10: "col10",
    col11: "col11",
    col12: "col12",
    col13: "col13"
  },

  {
    col1: "col1",
    col2: "col2",
    col3: "col3",
    col4: "col4",
    col5: "col5",
    col6: "col6",
    col7: "col7",
    col8: "col8",
    col9: "col9",
    col10: "col10",
    col11: "col11",
    col12: "col12",
    col13: "col13"
  }
];

export class ProvisioningMatrixList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      channels: "",
      channelsWithThumbnails: "",
      deleted: false,
      searchQuery: "",
      updatedList: "",
      deleteList: [],
      inactive: false,
      loading: false,
      hasSubmitted: null,
      showModal: false,
      handlerFunction: "",
      productId: "",
      errorMessage: ""
    };
    // this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
    this.onActivateProduct = this.onActivateProduct.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this);
  }

  render() {        
    const descStyle = {
      display: "-webkit-box",
      // height: '80px',
      fontSize: " 14px",
      lineHeight: "1",
      WebkitLineClamp: 8,
      WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical",
      overflow: "hidden",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      padding: "0",
      margin: ".75rem",
      // borderCollapse: "collapse",
      width: "100%"
    };
    let path = this.props.pathname.split("/");

    let dateTimeVisible;
    if (
      this.props.pathname.includes("vodList") ||
      this.props.pathname.includes("primaryPackage") ||
      this.props.pathname.includes("secondaryPackage") ||
      this.props.pathname.includes("dataBundle") ||
      this.props.pathname.includes("additionalScreens") ||
      this.props.pathname.includes("svod")
    ) {
      dateTimeVisible = true;
    } else {
      dateTimeVisible = false;
    }




    return (
      <>
        <style>
          {
            "table,th,td{border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #6c757d;padding: 8px; table-layout: fixed;}"
          }
        </style>

        <table id="mytable" className="table" style={descStyle}>
          <thead>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Connection No.</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Primary Package</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Secondary Package</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Extra Channels/Channel Bundles</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>SVOD</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>VOD/VOD Bundles</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Data Bundles</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Additional Screens</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Other Packages</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>SLT ACC No</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>SLT Tel No</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Mobile No</b>
            </th>
            <th className="table-header-font">
              <b>Connection Type</b>
            </th>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>

            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>


      </>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    ...state
    // vodData: channelSelectors.getVodData(state),
    // errorMessage: state.Channels.errorMessage,
    // purchaseOptions: state.ChannelFilter.purchaseOptions.purchaseOptions
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    // channelActions: bindActionCreators(channelActions, dispatch),
    purchaseOptionsActions: bindActionCreators(optionsListActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default withRouter(
  ProvisioningMatrixListHeaderView(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProvisioningMatrixList)
  )
);
```

I've used a class component and I want to map the array objects into table rows using .map in react..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can add the headers into another array.

Second, you don't need to specify the key values, if you know the headers already.

Finally, like the other answerer said, you can iterate through the array and render it.

Like this:

```
const headers = ['header1', 'header2', ..., 'header13'];

const data = [
  ["col1", ..., "col13"],
  ["col1", ..., "col13"],
];

render() {
  ...
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        {headers.map(h => <th>{h}</th>}
      <thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map(row => 
          <tr>
            {row.map(r => <td>{r}</td>}
          </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-newton-l3f7i) sandbox for exact implementation

If each item in `data` array corresponds to each row you can try out the following

```
  let data = [
      {
        col1: "col1",
        col2: "col2",
        col3: "col3",
        col4: "col4",
        col5: "col5",
        col6: "col6",
        col7: "col7",
        col8: "col8",
        col9: "col9",
        col10: "col10",
        col11: "col11",
        col12: "col12",
        col13: "col13"
      },

      {
        col1: "col1",
        col2: "col2",
        col3: "col3",
        col4: "col4",
        col5: "col5",
        col6: "col6",
        col7: "col7",
        col8: "col8",
        col9: "col9",
        col10: "col10",
        col11: "col11",
        col12: "col12",
        col13: "col13"
      }
    ];


      const renderTableBody = () => {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {data.map((row, i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={i}>
              {Object.entries(row).map(([key, value]) => {
                return <td key={key}>{value}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    );
  };
```

Feel free to shoot questions if any